# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages php ini (windows)

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed composer 1.10.5 php 7.4.1 after downloading reposotory from github I tried code 'composer install' I got an error(but works on project which I have created)
error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for league/flysystem 1.0.66 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.66].
- league/flysystem 1.0.66 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
```

Problem 2
    - league/flysystem 1.0.66 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.6.1 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.8 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.66].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v7.6.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.6.1].

enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: Look for `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in *php.ini* and remove the leading semi-colon (that quotes the line out in that file) - then restart Apache.

Comment: This method don't help me in php.ini I couldn't find ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll and erased 'extension='php_<ext>.dll' and restarted local setver but this don't help me